# Deny Multiple Logins

Tags: config, login

Is there any way to deny multiple user logins when using the same username & password?

So if a user is logged in, they can't login from another machine using the same login credentials.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Go to Admin -> Security and Privacy -> Security and Sessions and if you're using Sessions for the CP session type  then you can select "no" for Allow Multiple Log-ins From a Single Account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. go to Admin > Security & Privacy > Security and Session Preferences and disable "Allow multiple logins from  single account".

Comment: Will this setting work with Safe Cracker forms as well? If not, is there a different solution that will?